# How to count files in specific subdirectories of a parent directory?

Tags: linux, command-line

I use the `find . -type f | wc -l` command to count all the files in a regular directory, but in more specific cases if a directory contains many files, is it possible to specify this in the command?  In case I only want to count all the files in the `image` subdirectories for example. To know how many images (all in .jpeg) I have in total in `mydirectory`.

This command works `find /Users/mydirectory -type f -exec file --mime-type {}  \; | awk '{if ($NF == "image/jpeg") print $0 }'` but just display them. How to count them?

Finally the command `find /Users/mydirectory -type f -exec file --no-pad --mime-type {} + | awk '$NF == "image/jpeg" {$NF=""; sub(": $", ""); print}' | wc -l` seems to do the trick.

```
mydirectory/
    folder1/
       image/
       label/
    folder2/
       image/
       label/
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the impression that you are not aware of the `maxdepth` parameter of the `find` command, which indicates the depth of your search command: by using `find ... -maxdepth 1` you say that you only want to search within the directory itself. I believe this will solve your question.

Simple example: I created a subdirectory "tralala" and added two files, a subsubdirectory with one file, and I launched following command:

```
find tralala -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
```

The answer was `2`, which was correct, as you can see here from the amount "to be counted":

```
Prompt$ find tralala -ls
... drwxrwxrwx   ... tralala/              => is a directory, don't count.
... drwxrwxrwx   ... tralala/dir           => is a directory, don't count.
... -rwxrwxrwx   ... tralala/dir/test.txt  => is inside subdirectory, don't count.
... -rwxrwxrwx   ... tralala/test.txt      => is file inside directory, to be counted.
... -rwxrwxrwx   ... tralala/test2.txt     => is file inside directory, to be counted.
```

Comment: What would be the exact command with maxdepth?

Comment: Thanks Dominique, and do you have an idea for a better command? I have about 100k images in my directory but it takes an incredibly long time to show me the result.

Comment: 100k images? That's enormous! I can only think of one thing: the `find` instruction shows every single one of those files on your terminal, which gets refreshed every time. Although this does not consume a lot of time, the 100k makes it explode, so I see one possibility: redirect the results of your `find` command to a file, something like `find ... >result.txt`, and once this is done, count the amount of lines in that file `wc -l result.txt`. As you see, you'll need two separate commands for that, maybe it's a good idea to put them into a small shell script.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, I finally used a small python script.

Comment: You're welcome. In case my answer helped you, please upvote and/or accept it.